# Add new user : make the fields First Name and Last name required

Tags: functions, users, forms, permissions

I'm searching how to make First Name and Last name fields **required** when we add a new user. Right now only **username** and **Email** fields are required.

I found a way by adding `class="form-required"` for the first and last name fields on the file **user-new.php**.

But I'm looking for a method with adding code on **function.php** and not touch to the WordPress Core.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were looking to make the fields required in the Wordpress admin form for adding new user as i understood from your question, where the output is not filterable, you could basically do what you described (adding form-required) on browser side

```php
function se372358_add_required_to_first_name_last_name(string $type) {

    if ( 'add-new-user' === $type ) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('#first_name, #last_name')
                .parents('tr')
                .addClass('form-required')
                .find('label')
                .append(' <span class="description"><?php _e( '(required)' ); ?></span>');
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }

    return $type;
}

add_action('user_new_form', 'se372358_add_required_to_first_name_last_name');
```

**Edit**

In order to achieve the same on edit, you could use code like this:

```php
function se372358_add_required_to_first_name_last_name_alternative() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#createuser, #your-profile')
            .find('#first_name, #last_name')
            .parents('tr')
            .addClass('form-required')
            .find('label')
            .append(' <span class="description"><?php _e( '(required)' ); ?></span>');
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'se372358_add_required_to_first_name_last_name_alternative', 20);

function se372358_validate_first_name_last_name(WP_Error &$errors) {

    if (!isset($_POST['first_name']) || empty($_POST['first_name'])) {
        $errors->add( 'empty_first_name', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Please enter first name.' ), array( 'form-field' => 'first_name' ) );
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['last_name']) || empty($_POST['last_name'])) {
        $errors->add( 'empty_last_name', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Please enter last name.' ), array( 'form-field' => 'last_name' ) );
    }
    return $errors;
}

add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'se372358_validate_first_name_last_name' );
```

Comment: Thanks! That is almost what i need. Is it possible to make also the 2 fields (first and last name) required on profile.php and user-edit.php page on the backoffice with your method?

Comment: I've edited my original answer with solution for these pages.

Comment: Thanks. It works! one last question : on the original answer you speak about output not filterable what do you mean please?

Comment: It's only that it would be more convenient to add these form-required to the html directly, instead of adding them by javascript. But since the form does not have a filter, that you could use to modify the output, one has to do it like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without modifying the core files in WordPress, but for the sake of the same you have to override entire user-new.php file via `load-$pagenow` hook present in `wp-admin.php` file.

Try the following.

1. Create a folder named `core-template` inside your currently active theme. Create a file `user-new.php` inside that directory.
2. Paste following code to that file

```
<?php
/**
 * New User Administration Screen.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Administration
 */

/** WordPress Administration Bootstrap */
require_once( trailingslashit( ABSPATH ) . 'wp-admin/admin.php' );

if ( is_multisite() ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'create_users' ) && ! current_user_can( 'promote_users' ) ) {
        wp_die(
            '<h1>' . __( 'You need a higher level of permission.' ) . '</h1>' .
            '<p>' . __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to add users to this network.' ) . '</p>',
            403
        );
    }
} elseif ( ! current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) {
    wp_die(
        '<h1>' . __( 'You need a higher level of permission.' ) . '</h1>' .
        '<p>' . __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to create users.' ) . '</p>',
        403
    );
}

if ( is_multisite() ) {
    add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification_email', 'admin_created_user_email' );
}

if ( isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && 'adduser' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
    check_admin_referer( 'add-user', '_wpnonce_add-user' );

    $user_details = null;
    $user_email   = wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['email'] );
    if ( false !== strpos( $user_email, '@' ) ) {
        $user_details = get_user_by( 'email', $user_email );
    } else {
        if ( current_user_can( 'manage_network_users' ) ) {
            $user_details = get_user_by( 'login', $user_email );
        } else {
            wp_redirect( add_query_arg( array( 'update' => 'enter_email' ), 'user-new.php' ) );
            die();
        }
    }

    if ( ! $user_details ) {
        wp_redirect( add_query_arg( array( 'update' => 'does_not_exist' ), 'user-new.php' ) );
        die();
    }

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'promote_user', $user_details->ID ) ) {
        wp_die(
            '<h1>' . __( 'You need a higher level of permission.' ) . '</h1>' .
            '<p>' . __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to add users to this network.' ) . '</p>',
            403
        );
    }

    // Adding an existing user to this blog
    $new_user_email = $user_details->user_email;
    $redirect       = 'user-new.php';
    $username       = $user_details->user_login;
    $user_id        = $user_details->ID;
    if ( $username != null && array_key_exists( $blog_id, get_blogs_of_user( $user_id ) ) ) {
        $redirect = add_query_arg( array( 'update' => 'addexisting' ), 'user-new.php' );
    } else {
        if ( isset( $_POST['noconfirmation'] ) && current_user_can( 'manage_network_users' ) ) {
            $result = add_existing_user_to_blog(
                array(
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'role'    => $_REQUEST['role'],
                )
            );

            if ( ! is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
                $redirect = add_query_arg(
                    array(
                        'update'  => 'addnoconfirmation',
                        'user_id' => $user_id,
                    ),
                    'user-new.php'
                );
            } else {
                $redirect = add_query_arg( array( 'update' => 'could_not_add' ), 'user-new.php' );
            }
        } else {
            $newuser_key = wp_generate_password( 20, false );
            add_option(
                'new_user_' . $newuser_key,
                array(
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'email'   => $user_details->user_email,
                    'role'    => $_REQUEST['role'],
                )
            );

            $roles = get_editable_roles();
            $role  = $roles[ $_REQUEST['role'] ];

            /**
             * Fires immediately after a user is invited to join a site, but before the notification is sent.
             *
             * @since 4.4.0
             *
             * @param int    $user_id     The invited user's ID.
             * @param array  $role        The role of invited user.
             * @param string $newuser_key The key of the invitation.
             */
            do_action( 'invite_user', $user_id, $role, $newuser_key );

            $switched_locale = switch_to_locale( get_user_locale( $user_details ) );

            /* translators: 1: Site title, 2: Site URL, 3: User role, 4: Activation URL. */
            $message = __(
                'Hi,

You\'ve been invited to join \'%1$s\' at
%2$s with the role of %3$s.

Please click the following link to confirm the invite:
%4$s'
            );

            wp_mail(
                $new_user_email,
                sprintf(
                    /* translators: Joining confirmation notification email subject. %s: Site title. */
                    __( '[%s] Joining Confirmation' ),
                    wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ) )
                ),
                sprintf(
                    $message,
                    get_option( 'blogname' ),
                    home_url(),
                    wp_specialchars_decode( translate_user_role( $role['name'] ) ),
                    home_url( "/newbloguser/$newuser_key/" )
                )
            );

            if ( $switched_locale ) {
                restore_previous_locale();
            }

            $redirect = add_query_arg( array( 'update' => 'add' ), 'user-new.php' );
        }
    }
    wp_redirect( $redirect );
    die();
} elseif ( isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && 'createuser' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
    check_admin_referer( 'create-user', '_wpnonce_create-user' );

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) {
        wp_die(
            '<h1>' . __( 'You need a higher level of permission.' ) . '</h1>' .
            '<p>' . __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to create users.' ) . '</p>',
            403
        );
    }

    if ( ! is_multisite() ) {
        $user_id = edit_user();

        if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
            $add_user_errors = $user_id;
        } else {
            if ( current_user_can( 'list_users' ) ) {
                $redirect = 'users.php?update=add&id=' . $user_id;
            } else {
                $redirect = add_query_arg( 'update', 'add', 'user-new.php' );
            }
            wp_redirect( $redirect );
            die();
        }
    } else {
        // Adding a new user to this site
        $new_user_email = wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['email'] );
        $user_details   = wpmu_validate_user_signup( $_REQUEST['user_login'], $new_user_email );
        if ( is_wp_error( $user_details['errors'] ) && $user_details['errors']->has_errors() ) {
            $add_user_errors = $user_details['errors'];
        } else {
            /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/user.php */
            $new_user_login = apply_filters( 'pre_user_login', sanitize_user( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['user_login'] ), true ) );
            if ( isset( $_POST['noconfirmation'] ) && current_user_can( 'manage_network_users' ) ) {
                add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification', '__return_false' ); // Disable confirmation email
                add_filter( 'wpmu_welcome_user_notification', '__return_false' ); // Disable welcome email
            }
            wpmu_signup_user(
                $new_user_login,
                $new_user_email,
                array(
                    'add_to_blog' => get_current_blog_id(),
                    'new_role'    => $_REQUEST['role'],
                )
            );
            if ( isset( $_POST['noconfirmation'] ) && current_user_can( 'manage_network_users' ) ) {
                $key      = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT activation_key FROM {$wpdb->signups} WHERE user_login = %s AND user_email = %s", $new_user_login, $new_user_email ) );
                $new_user = wpmu_activate_signup( $key );
                if ( is_wp_error( $new_user ) ) {
                    $redirect = add_query_arg( array( 'update' => 'addnoconfirmation' ), 'user-new.php' );
                } elseif ( ! is_user_member_of_blog( $new_user['user_id'] ) ) {
                    $redirect = add_query_arg( array( 'update' => 'created_could_not_add' ), 'user-new.php' );
                } else {
                    $redirect = add_query_arg(
                        array(
                            'update'  => 'addnoconfirmation',
                            'user_id' => $new_user['user_id'],
                        ),
                        'user-new.php'
                    );
                }
            } else {
                $redirect = add_query_arg( array( 'update' => 'newuserconfirmation' ), 'user-new.php' );
            }
            wp_redirect( $redirect );
            die();
        }
    }
}

$title       = __( 'Add New User' );
$parent_file = 'users.php';

$do_both = false;
if ( is_multisite() && current_user_can( 'promote_users' ) && current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) {
    $do_both = true;
}

$help = '<p>' . __( 'To add a new user to your site, fill in the form on this screen and click the Add New User button at the bottom.' ) . '</p>';

if ( is_multisite() ) {
    $help .= '<p>' . __( 'Because this is a multisite installation, you may add accounts that already exist on the Network by specifying a username or email, and defining a role. For more options, such as specifying a password, you have to be a Network Administrator and use the hover link under an existing user&#8217;s name to Edit the user profile under Network Admin > All Users.' ) . '</p>' .
    '<p>' . __( 'New users will receive an email letting them know they&#8217;ve been added as a user for your site. This email will also contain their password. Check the box if you don&#8217;t want the user to receive a welcome email.' ) . '</p>';
} else {
    $help .= '<p>' . __( 'New users are automatically assigned a password, which they can change after logging in. You can view or edit the assigned password by clicking the Show Password button. The username cannot be changed once the user has been added.' ) . '</p>' .

    '<p>' . __( 'By default, new users will receive an email letting them know they&#8217;ve been added as a user for your site. This email will also contain a password reset link. Uncheck the box if you don&#8217;t want to send the new user a welcome email.' ) . '</p>';
}

$help .= '<p>' . __( 'Remember to click the Add New User button at the bottom of this screen when you are finished.' ) . '</p>';

get_current_screen()->add_help_tab(
    array(
        'id'      => 'overview',
        'title'   => __( 'Overview' ),
        'content' => $help,
    )
);

get_current_screen()->add_help_tab(
    array(
        'id'      => 'user-roles',
        'title'   => __( 'User Roles' ),
        'content' => '<p>' . __( 'Here is a basic overview of the different user roles and the permissions associated with each one:' ) . '</p>' .
                            '<ul>' .
                            '<li>' . __( 'Subscribers can read comments/comment/receive newsletters, etc. but cannot create regular site content.' ) . '</li>' .
                            '<li>' . __( 'Contributors can write and manage their posts but not publish posts or upload media files.' ) . '</li>' .
                            '<li>' . __( 'Authors can publish and manage their own posts, and are able to upload files.' ) . '</li>' .
                            '<li>' . __( 'Editors can publish posts, manage posts as well as manage other people&#8217;s posts, etc.' ) . '</li>' .
                            '<li>' . __( 'Administrators have access to all the administration features.' ) . '</li>' .
                            '</ul>',
    )
);

get_current_screen()->set_help_sidebar(
    '<p><strong>' . __( 'For more information:' ) . '</strong></p>' .
    '<p>' . __( '<a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/users-add-new-screen/">Documentation on Adding New Users</a>' ) . '</p>' .
    '<p>' . __( '<a href="https://wordpress.org/support/">Support</a>' ) . '</p>'
);

wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-ajax-response' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'user-profile' );

/**
 * Filters whether to enable user auto-complete for non-super admins in Multisite.
 *
 * @since 3.4.0
 *
 * @param bool $enable Whether to enable auto-complete for non-super admins. Default false.
 */
if ( is_multisite() && current_user_can( 'promote_users' ) && ! wp_is_large_network( 'users' )
    && ( current_user_can( 'manage_network_users' ) || apply_filters( 'autocomplete_users_for_site_admins', false ) )
) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'user-suggest' );
}

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-header.php' );

if ( isset( $_GET['update'] ) ) {
    $messages = array();
    if ( is_multisite() ) {
        $edit_link = '';
        if ( ( isset( $_GET['user_id'] ) ) ) {
            $user_id_new = absint( $_GET['user_id'] );
            if ( $user_id_new ) {
                $edit_link = esc_url( add_query_arg( 'wp_http_referer', urlencode( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ), get_edit_user_link( $user_id_new ) ) );
            }
        }

        switch ( $_GET['update'] ) {
            case 'newuserconfirmation':
                $messages[] = __( 'Invitation email sent to new user. A confirmation link must be clicked before their account is created.' );
                break;
            case 'add':
                $messages[] = __( 'Invitation email sent to user. A confirmation link must be clicked for them to be added to your site.' );
                break;
            case 'addnoconfirmation':
                $message = __( 'User has been added to your site.' );

                if ( $edit_link ) {
                    $message .= sprintf( ' <a href="%s">%s</a>', $edit_link, __( 'Edit user' ) );
                }

                $messages[] = $message;
                break;
            case 'addexisting':
                $messages[] = __( 'That user is already a member of this site.' );
                break;
            case 'could_not_add':
                $add_user_errors = new WP_Error( 'could_not_add', __( 'That user could not be added to this site.' ) );
                break;
            case 'created_could_not_add':
                $add_user_errors = new WP_Error( 'created_could_not_add', __( 'User has been created, but could not be added to this site.' ) );
                break;
            case 'does_not_exist':
                $add_user_errors = new WP_Error( 'does_not_exist', __( 'The requested user does not exist.' ) );
                break;
            case 'enter_email':
                $add_user_errors = new WP_Error( 'enter_email', __( 'Please enter a valid email address.' ) );
                break;
        }
    } else {
        if ( 'add' == $_GET['update'] ) {
            $messages[] = __( 'User added.' );
        }
    }
}
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h1 id="add-new-user">
<?php
if ( current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) {
    _e( 'Add New User' );
} elseif ( current_user_can( 'promote_users' ) ) {
    _e( 'Add Existing User' );
}
?>
</h1>

<?php if ( isset( $errors ) && is_wp_error( $errors ) ) : ?>
    <div class="error">
        <ul>
        <?php
        foreach ( $errors->get_error_messages() as $err ) {
            echo "<li>$err</li>\n";
        }
        ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
endif;

if ( ! empty( $messages ) ) {
    foreach ( $messages as $msg ) {
        echo '<div id="message" class="updated notice is-dismissible"><p>' . $msg . '</p></div>';
    }
}
?>

<?php if ( isset( $add_user_errors ) && is_wp_error( $add_user_errors ) ) : ?>
    <div class="error">
        <?php
        foreach ( $add_user_errors->get_error_messages() as $message ) {
            echo "<p>$message</p>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="ajax-response"></div>

<?php
if ( is_multisite() && current_user_can( 'promote_users' ) ) {
    if ( $do_both ) {
        echo '<h2 id="add-existing-user">' . __( 'Add Existing User' ) . '</h2>';
    }
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_network_users' ) ) {
        echo '<p>' . __( 'Enter the email address of an existing user on this network to invite them to this site. That person will be sent an email asking them to confirm the invite.' ) . '</p>';
        $label = __( 'Email' );
        $type  = 'email';
    } else {
        echo '<p>' . __( 'Enter the email address or username of an existing user on this network to invite them to this site. That person will be sent an email asking them to confirm the invite.' ) . '</p>';
        $label = __( 'Email or Username' );
        $type  = 'text';
    }
    ?>
<form method="post" name="adduser" id="adduser" class="validate" novalidate="novalidate"
    <?php
    /**
     * Fires inside the adduser form tag.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     */
    do_action( 'user_new_form_tag' );
    ?>
>
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="adduser" />
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'add-user', '_wpnonce_add-user' ); ?>

<table class="form-table" role="presentation">
    <tr class="form-field form-required">
        <th scope="row"><label for="adduser-email"><?php echo $label; ?></label></th>
        <td><input name="email" type="<?php echo $type; ?>" id="adduser-email" class="wp-suggest-user" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="adduser-role"><?php _e( 'Role' ); ?></label></th>
        <td><select name="role" id="adduser-role">
            <?php wp_dropdown_roles( get_option( 'default_role' ) ); ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php if ( current_user_can( 'manage_network_users' ) ) { ?>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Skip Confirmation Email' ); ?></th>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="noconfirmation" id="adduser-noconfirmation" value="1" />
            <label for="adduser-noconfirmation"><?php _e( 'Add the user without sending an email that requires their confirmation.' ); ?></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
    <?php
    /**
     * Fires at the end of the new user form.
     *
     * Passes a contextual string to make both types of new user forms
     * uniquely targetable. Contexts are 'add-existing-user' (Multisite),
     * and 'add-new-user' (single site and network admin).
     *
     * @since 3.7.0
     *
     * @param string $type A contextual string specifying which type of new user form the hook follows.
     */
    do_action( 'user_new_form', 'add-existing-user' );
    ?>
    <?php submit_button( __( 'Add Existing User' ), 'primary', 'adduser', true, array( 'id' => 'addusersub' ) ); ?>
</form>
    <?php
} // is_multisite()

if ( current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) {
    if ( $do_both ) {
        echo '<h2 id="create-new-user">' . __( 'Add New User' ) . '</h2>';
    }
    ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Create a brand new user and add them to this site.' ); ?></p>
<form method="post" name="createuser" id="createuser" class="validate" novalidate="novalidate"
    <?php
    /** This action is documented in wp-admin/user-new.php */
    do_action( 'user_new_form_tag' );
    ?>
>
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="createuser" />
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'create-user', '_wpnonce_create-user' ); ?>
    <?php
    // Load up the passed data, else set to a default.
    $creating = isset( $_POST['createuser'] );

    $new_user_login             = $creating && isset( $_POST['user_login'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['user_login'] ) : '';
    $new_user_firstname         = $creating && isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';
    $new_user_lastname          = $creating && isset( $_POST['last_name'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['last_name'] ) : '';
    $new_user_email             = $creating && isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) : '';
    $new_user_uri               = $creating && isset( $_POST['url'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['url'] ) : '';
    $new_user_role              = $creating && isset( $_POST['role'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['role'] ) : '';
    $new_user_send_notification = $creating && ! isset( $_POST['send_user_notification'] ) ? false : true;
    $new_user_ignore_pass       = $creating && isset( $_POST['noconfirmation'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['noconfirmation'] ) : '';

    ?>
<table class="form-table" role="presentation">
    <tr class="form-field form-required">
        <th scope="row"><label for="user_login"><?php _e( 'Username' ); ?> <span class="description"><?php _e( '(required)' ); ?></span></label></th>
        <td><input name="user_login" type="text" id="user_login" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $new_user_login ); ?>" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" maxlength="60" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field form-required">
        <th scope="row"><label for="email"><?php _e( 'Email' ); ?> <span class="description"><?php _e( '(required)' ); ?></span></label></th>
        <td><input name="email" type="email" id="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $new_user_email ); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <?php if ( ! is_multisite() ) { ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="first_name"><?php _e( 'First Name (Required)' ); ?> </label></th>
        <td><input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" class="form-required" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $new_user_firstname ); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="last_name"><?php _e( 'Last Name (Required)' ); ?> </label></th>
        <td><input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" class="form-required" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $new_user_lastname ); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="url"><?php _e( 'Website' ); ?></label></th>
        <td><input name="url" type="url" id="url" class="code" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $new_user_uri ); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field form-required user-pass1-wrap">
        <th scope="row">
            <label for="pass1">
                <?php _e( 'Password' ); ?>
                <span class="description hide-if-js"><?php _e( '(required)' ); ?></span>
            </label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input class="hidden" value=" " /><!-- #24364 workaround -->
            <button type="button" class="button wp-generate-pw hide-if-no-js"><?php _e( 'Show password' ); ?></button>
            <div class="wp-pwd hide-if-js">
                <?php $initial_password = wp_generate_password( 24 ); ?>
                <span class="password-input-wrapper">
                    <input type="password" name="pass1" id="pass1" class="regular-text" autocomplete="off" data-reveal="1" data-pw="<?php echo esc_attr( $initial_password ); ?>" aria-describedby="pass-strength-result" />
                </span>
                <button type="button" class="button wp-hide-pw hide-if-no-js" data-toggle="0" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Hide password' ); ?>">
                    <span class="dashicons dashicons-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="text"><?php _e( 'Hide' ); ?></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="button wp-cancel-pw hide-if-no-js" data-toggle="0" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Cancel password change' ); ?>">
                    <span class="dashicons dashicons-no" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="text"><?php _e( 'Cancel' ); ?></span>
                </button>
                <div style="display:none" id="pass-strength-result" aria-live="polite"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field form-required user-pass2-wrap hide-if-js">
        <th scope="row"><label for="pass2"><?php _e( 'Repeat Password' ); ?> <span class="description"><?php _e( '(required)' ); ?></span></label></th>
        <td>
        <input name="pass2" type="password" id="pass2" autocomplete="off" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pw-weak">
        <th><?php _e( 'Confirm Password' ); ?></th>
        <td>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="pw_weak" class="pw-checkbox" />
                <?php _e( 'Confirm use of weak password' ); ?>
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Send User Notification' ); ?></th>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="send_user_notification" id="send_user_notification" value="1" <?php checked( $new_user_send_notification ); ?> />
            <label for="send_user_notification"><?php _e( 'Send the new user an email about their account.' ); ?></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } // !is_multisite ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="role"><?php _e( 'Role' ); ?></label></th>
        <td><select name="role" id="role">
            <?php
            if ( ! $new_user_role ) {
                $new_user_role = ! empty( $current_role ) ? $current_role : get_option( 'default_role' );
            }
            wp_dropdown_roles( $new_user_role );
            ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php if ( is_multisite() && current_user_can( 'manage_network_users' ) ) { ?>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Skip Confirmation Email' ); ?></th>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="noconfirmation" id="noconfirmation" value="1" <?php checked( $new_user_ignore_pass ); ?> />
            <label for="noconfirmation"><?php _e( 'Add the user without sending an email that requires their confirmation.' ); ?></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>

    <?php
    /** This action is documented in wp-admin/user-new.php */
    do_action( 'user_new_form', 'add-new-user' );
    ?>

    <?php submit_button( __( 'Add New User' ), 'primary', 'createuser', true, array( 'id' => 'createusersub' ) ); ?>

</form>
<?php } // current_user_can('create_users') ?>
</div>
<?php
include( trailingslashit( ABSPATH ) . 'wp-admin/admin-footer.php' );
```

Note that this is the same code as user-new.php, but now you have the control of what needs to be changed in that file.

3. Now, you need to tell wordpress to load that file instead of its core `user-new.php`, create following function in functions.php of your theme.

```
function se_372358_user_new_template() {
    require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/core-template/user-new.php' );
    die();
}
add_action( 'load-user-new.php', 'se_372358_user_new_template' );
```

You should now be able to see your new template being loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

WordPress Codex Says:

The following example demonstrates how to add a "First Name" field to the registration form as a required field. First Name is one of WordPress's built-in user meta types, but you can define any field or custom user meta you want. Just keep in mind that if you create custom user meta, you may need to create additional admin UI as well.

```php
//1. Add a new form element...
add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' );
function myplugin_register_form() {

    $first_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';
        
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="first_name"><?php _e( 'First Name', 'mydomain' ) ?><br />
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr(  $first_name  ); ?>" size="25" /></label>
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    //2. Add validation. In this case, we make sure first_name is required.
    add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
    function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {
        
        if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) && trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) == '' ) {
        $errors->add( 'first_name_error', sprintf('<strong>%s</strong>: %s',__( 'ERROR', 'mydomain' ),__( 'You must include a first name.', 'mydomain' ) ) );

        }

        return $errors;
    }

    //3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta.
    add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );
    function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['first_name'] ) );
        }
    }
```

this code can be added to functions.php file,

further info could be found on [Wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form)

Comment: Thanks for your reply